# Why do I recieve an "Exception in thread "main"java.lang.NumberFormat: null..." after clicking the "cancel" button?

Tags: java, io, switch-statement, nested-loops

After I run the program, a window pops up and there are two buttons. If I click the "Cancel" button, the program exits but I receive this message: `Exception in thread "main"java.lang.NumberFormat: null...`.
Can someone explain what this is and how to fix it? Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
public class Driver12 //class
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      while(true)
      {
         int rows = Integer.parseInt(
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many rows? (-1 to quit)"));
         if(rows == -1)
         {
            System.out.println("Bye-bye!");
            System.exit(0);
         }
         String message = "What type? (1-4)";
         message = message + "\n1. Standard";
         message = message + "\n2. Backward";
         message = message + "\n3. Pyramid";
         message = message + "\n4. Box with X";
         int type = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message));
         switch(type)
         {
            case 1: standard(rows);
               break;
            case 2: backward(rows);
               break;
            case 3: pyramid(rows);
               break;
            case 4: box(rows);
               break;
            default: System.out.println("Not a valid type.");
               break;
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
   public static void standard(int n)
   {
      for(int r = 1; r <= n; r++)
      {
         for(int c = 1; c <= r; c++)
            System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
   public static void backward(int n)
   {
      System.out.println("This type is not currently supported.");
   }
   public static void pyramid(int n)
   {
      System.out.println("This type is not currently supported.");
   }
   public static void box(int n)
   {
      System.out.println("This type is not currently supported.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you cancel the dialog, `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` returns `null` so `Integer.parseInt` throws a `NumberFormatException`.

You can solve this by replacing

```
int type = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message));
```

with

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
int type = input == null ? -1 : Integer.parseInt(input);
```

However a better solution would be not to use `Integer.parseInt` at all. You could simply `switch` on the `String` returned by `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit cancel in a `JOptionPane` input box, what actually happens is that the variable that is reading the input is being given a null value, the exception is thrown when it tries to parse that in an integer because null is not an integer.
Try using a `try-catch` statement to prevent the program from crashing when cancel is pressed. As an added bonus it also would prevent a problem from other invalid inputs, such as letters.

Just changing the relevant part to this should do the trick.

```
try{
  int rows = Integer.parseInt(
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                 "How many rows? (-1 to quit)"));
}catch(Exception e){
  return;
}
```

You can change the `return;` at the end of the statement to whatever you wish to appear in the case of an exception occurring. However, leaving the `return;` at the end will allow the user to re-enter the input.